# How to preserve double quotations using OkHttp

Tags: android, okhttp

I am dealing with an api where I need to provide a JSON array as a query parameter in a POST request. The quotation has to be in the url, but OkHttp and HttpURL keep converting it to `%22`. The API will not recognize this and returns an error code. How can I make OkHttp preserve the quotation in the request. The code I am dealing with looks like this:

```
public static void post(String url, String[][] requestParams, Callback callback) {
    HttpUrl httpUrl = addParamsToURL(getAbsoluteUrl(url), requestParams);


    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(httpUrl)
            .addHeader("app", Prefs.getString(Constants.HEADER_APP, null))
            .addHeader("authoToken", Prefs.getString(Constants.HEADER_AUTH_TOKEN, null))
            .post(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), ""))
            .build();
    okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(callback);
}

private static HttpUrl addParamsToURL(String url, String[][] requestParams) {
    HttpUrl httpUrl = HttpUrl.parse(url);
    HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = httpUrl.newBuilder();
    for(int i = 0, size = requestParams.length; i < size; i++ ) {
        urlBuilder.addEncodedQueryParameter(requestParams[i][0], requestParams[i][1]);
    }
    return urlBuilder.build();
}
```

I need the url the request goes to to look like `https://www.baseurl.com/path?queryName=["email@domain.com"]` but instead it looks like `https://www.baseurl.com/path/?queryName=[%22email@domain.com%22]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, you should strongly consider what [Jesse Wilson](https://twitter.com/jessewilson?lang=en) says, but as a workaround you can see what people suggest doing in these threads:

- [thread 1](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1407)
- [thread 2](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1199)

Particularly, [Mike Nakhimovich suggests](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1199#issuecomment-210901184) replacing encoded character back through interceptors:

```
request.url(originalRequest.url().toString().replace("%3D","="));
```

Comment: It turned out that the problem was _not_ the double quotations but was a typo further up the line. However I know it is an issue for many people whose servers are set up poorly so I'm choosing your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Fix the server. OkHttp is consistent with web browsers which all encode `"` to `%22` in query strings.

Chrome:

```
GET /?a=[%22email@domain.com%22] HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

Firefox:

```
GET /?a=[%22email@domain.com%22] HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
```

Safari

```
GET /?a=[%22email@domain.com%22] HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/602.4.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.3 Safari/602.4.8
```